# Move Config DB to new SQL server

Tags: stsadm

Our SQLserver db containing the SharePoint config db went down, hardware failure, the content is on a different server, managed to get the config db from backup,

i ran stsadm -o delete configdb, but I keep getting 'access denied' when I try to reconnect to the old config db on the new server from the command:

stsdam -o setconfigdb -connect -databaseserver (newservername) -databasename SP2007_config -farmuser (SP farm admin user) -farmpassword (password)

after playing around with permissions and making sure everything is well permission wise, i got:

a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server.... (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - could not open a connection to SQL server)

allow remote connections to server is turned on, I am running stsadm on the same server because its all a 'one box' farm expect the config db was on a seperate box which is down????

tried psconfig and it hangs on;

Performing configuration task 2 of 3
Connecting to the configuration database... THEN

Failed to connect to the configuration database.
An exception of type System.Security.SecurityException was thrown. Additional exception information: Access denied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont mention the version of SharePoint you are using, but since you mention stsadm i am gonna assume you are using SP2007.

You should follow [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723%28v=Office.12%29.aspx) guide on technet. Be aware that the procedure varies depending on if you are running named instances (alias) or not.

For SP2010 use [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723.aspx) article instead.

Comment: thank you :) it was SQL Server Native Client Network Utility that i was missing

Comment: after having successfully moved the configdb, i ran configuration wizard and it confirmed the farm was now using the configdb on the new server but while troubleshooting why 'search' is not working, i noticed that under CA > Servers in Farm, it says the config database is on the old server even though configuration wizard says its on the new server?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue but changing the parentID in the config database
check the link below to the post

http://www.sharepointtechs.com/moss-2007-showing-old-server-as-configuration-database-server/

Answer (score -1):

Remember to view if there exists a string connection of SharePoint_Config data base in SharePoint Server's Registry